# Adding a new table row using HTMX

Tags: django, htmx

I am trying to add a new table row with Htmx. By clicking the "Add A New Row" button, a new row should be added to the table.
I can't get the row in the secondary_hx.html to be added to the table, instead it results as three forms next to each other without  or .
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.
My code is like this:

main.html:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="Tbody">
      <tr>
          <td>
             <button class="add_button"
                type="submit"
                hx-post="/add_row/"
                hx-target="#Tbody"
                hx-swap="beforeend"
                >
                  Add A New Row
             </button>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

partials/secondary_hx.html:

```
<tr hx-target="this"
    hx-swap="outerHTML">
    <td>{{ form.a }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.b }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.c }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your `partials/secondary_hx.html` file looks like it is the HTML for rendering 3 forms next to each other. What exactly do you expect that to render as?

Comment: I expect when the button "Add A New Row" clicked, a new row with three forms (cells) to be added.

Comment: So you expect a new row with three forms to be added, but your problem statement is that you are getting three forms next to each other? I think you have left something out of your problem statement.